# How i can decrease the Load time of my website

Tags: performance, laravel-5, request, page-load-time

Thankyou in advance :)

I am developing a website in laravel. My website is Optimized,

**But it's Loading time is 13s**

I Optimize my website by doing some steps and achieved 81 % score in google pageSpeedInsight

1. Use Google Fonts (Previously loading from the server)
2. Bootstrap (include bootstrap using CDN)
3. minified javascript
4. minified CSS
5. compress images (reduced the images size without compromising quality )
6. convert images into Base64 (to reduce the request)

The Bottleneck is my Loading time which is **13s**

Following Reason **might** be the issue

- The file size is 1.4mb take almost 7s to load 
  [image]
- The big issue  are images so when the landing page is rendered it almost requested 50+ images

  . But even reduced the number of requests it's loading time is **13s**

  **Question**

  1. What will the roadmap to achieving the **4s load time** of the website?
  2. How can I achieve this **4s load time** of the website

Thank you very much for helping me out I been searching this out for a very long time

I appreciate your help

Comment: In terms of images, have you taken a look at https://cloudinary.com, this may help in delivering image assets faster

Comment: For css, you could combine bootstrap and your css into one file, then use https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss to remove any unused css from your new css file.

Comment: Also, is it possible to lazy load some assets on your site (images, content)?

Comment: @thisiskelvin I am looking into cloudinary.com is there anything else that i can do with in my code

Comment: Have you thought about caching the returned `view()` so that your application isn't performing the same logic repetatively. This is especially good for pages which aren't updated frequently.

Comment: @thisiskelvin i agree with that, but the focus is to speed up the page render first time in the browser

Comment: Do you have a link to the project in question?

Comment: sure can you please share your email?

Answer (score 1):

This is really hard to answer in the abstract.

In general, I've found that the 80/20 rule applies with page performance - 80% of the time is usually spent on 20% of assets that you need to load. The problem is that each website can have a different 20% - however, with a 13 second load time, there are some likely candidates.

**Large assets**, typically video, audio or image files. A 1.4Mb image file is just about acceptable, but smaller is definitely better. On a 512K download link, that file would take well over 20 seconds to download; on aDSL (around 6Mbps), it's still a few seconds. Ideally, you want images to be <500Kb.

**Many assets** even if you have optimized all the images, having many large-ish images will make the page slow. If that's unavoidable due to the design of the site, consider lazy loading - only load an image once it appears in the browser's view port.

**Slow server-side rendering of the page** if your .php files are slow, the website will be slow.

Combining/minifying CSS/JS, using CDNs all help, but typically only once you have the other things sorted out - in my experience!

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I have checked my images are all less than 500kb, does the document load time is more because I call the helper function in the blade which convert the images into base64 and display??

Comment: If you're doing that on each page request, rather  than serving from server-side cache, then yes, it probably is!